# Multiple core usage on Adobe Flash 10

Tags: flash, cpu, p2p, multicore, multiplayer

I'm developing a p2p mutliplayer game using adobe rtmfp server on facebook using flex 4. I have box2d for physics engine and the hardware acceleration is on. In 60fps, Average cpu cost for 6 players room is %40 for 1.86mhz intel core 2 duo. But in 8 and more players rooms, the cpu usage increases to %50 and fps drops to 50. I'm guessing that flash player uses only 1 core in full performance and resting the other. However I need all cores for 8+ rooms to simulate 60 fps smooth game. Is there a way to make flash use multiple cores at once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, other than to use pixel bender to do whatever number crunching is possible. Pixel bender runs on it's own thread independent of the flash VM (if you use shader jobs properly). See my answer here:

[Flash parallel programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606195/flash-parallel-programming/5606272#5606272)