# Socket asynchronism in as3

Tags: multithreading, actionscript-3, flash, sockets

Sockets with as3:

```
socket.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onData);

private function onData(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    socket.readBytes(buffer, 0, socket.bytesAvailable);
    // doing some processing using buffer info
    // maybe this can delay a lot, for ex, 10 seconds
}
```

When the event listener calls onData will it wait to this function to finish doing onData computation after calling another onData event right?

As3 can't be multithread anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the flash virtual machine only executes actionscript in a single thread. The only way to make a "multi threaded" application is to use Pixel Bender Kernels to do number crunching for you. You can find more information about all this on another answer I've given that has much more details: [Flash parallel programming](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606195/flash-parallel-programming/5606272#5606272)