# What happens if from JS I call SWF which already is busy handling another call from JS?

Tags: javascript, multithreading, actionscript-3, externalinterface

JS-to-AS3 callbacks work in kinda asynchronous way right? So for example if I ask SWF to download some file, which may take some time (depending on the size of that file), and while it downloads it, ask it to do some other operation (suppose SWF has several callbacks for various purposes), what happens in this case? Does SWF continue to download file and handle my second request in a different thread maybe, or it crashes, or throws some error?

I know this is a good case for some testing, but I wonder if anyone has already done that, or maybe there is public info on the case that I cannot find?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5606195/flash-parallel-programming

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking the JS/AS3 bridge is synchronous, however the answer will depend on the implementation of the function on the AS3 side.

If the AS3 side is an async operation then you need to work out a callback strategy so the AS3 can call back a JS function when finished.